# How can I undelete this to answers

Tags: discussion, support

I posted this two answers, although they work and I test the solution, it seems that there is not very obvious since they were deleted on sight with this comment:

> Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer
>   the original question.

I think they answer the OP question and/or offer a different alternative from the other answer and it can be tested, can you help me with hint on how to improve them so they can be undeleted:

https://superuser.com/a/1365115/151294

https://superuser.com/a/1365119/151294

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this one [Remove the password from Microsoft Access file](https://superuser.com/questions/180392/remove-the-password-from-microsoft-access-file/1365119#1365119) you assume the question is about Ubuntu/Debian, but the other answers already there indicate it is not.

For this one [Opening mdb files in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/34326/opening-mdb-files-in-ubuntu/1365115#1365115) your answer duplicates the answers already given. Yes, it adds more and helpful information, but no, there are already two other answers suggesting the MDB Tools.

For both questions, they are very old, already have answers, and your adding information, especially duplicate (the second) or entirely incorrect (the first) information does not add anything to the conversation.

There is rarely a reason to visit questions that already have answers, especially questions years old. The reasons one might actually add something would be if there is new information, a new solution, a version of the software in question that resolves the bug, or an entirely unseen fix that completely solves the problem.

On another note, you appear to have searched for certain keywords and then just copy-pasted a solution. This also is likely to raise spam flags which brings your answers to the attention of Mods.

Keep contributing, but I'd advise you to

- stick to fresh questions
- avoid copy-pasting the same answer to multiple places
- make sure your answer is completely unique
- read the questions AND the existing answers more carefully

Comment: I rarely see the use of submitting an answer to old questions dealing with solutions only applicable to newer versions of the software that was asked about.  If the old solution no longer is applicable to the newer version that sounds like a new question.  You really should submit a similar question specifically for that newer version and self-answer instead of submitting an answer that is only applicable to the newer versions.  We do that all the time for questions about operating systems

Comment: Some questions are such that an upgrade to a version with a fix IS acceptable. Others are very much version-locked. The first type have actually have a change in the correct answer as features in new releases change. The latter, of course, doesn't.

Comment: @music2year - I rarely see an answer submitted for a newer version that is applicable to the version the author of the question was using.  Now while it’s gtea to help everyone, as an answer author, answering the authors question should be primary while secondary is helping everyone (IMO)